# How to delete every Pod in a Kubernetes namespace

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kubernetes, kubectl

#### Take this scenario:

[image]

I want to delete every **running** pod **automatically** using the **Commandline** without having to type `kubectl delete pod <pod_name> -n <namespace>` for each pod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `awk` to filter pod names based on their `STATUS==RUNNING`. Below code will delete all(in Running state) the pods from `$NAMESPACE` namespace.

```
 kubectl  get pod -n $NAMESPACE|awk '$3=="Running"{print $1}'
```

Example:

```
for pod in $(kubectl  get pod -n $NAMESPACE |awk '$3=="Running"{print $1}'); do
    kubectl delete pod -n $NAMESPACE $pod
done
```

**OR**

You may use `jsonpath`,

```
NAMESPACE=mynamespace
for pod in $(kubectl  get pod -n $NAMESPACE -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.phase=="Running")].metadata.name}{"\n"}'); do
    kubectl delete pod -n $NAMESPACE "$pod"
done
```

NOTE: Above code will cause deletion of all the pods in `$NAMESPACE` variable.

**Example:**

```
kubectl get pod -n mynamespace
NAME        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
foo-mh6j7   0/1     Completed   0          5d3h
nginx       1/1     Running     2          7d10h
mongo       2/2     Running     12         57d
busybox     1/1     Running     187        61d
```

`jsonpath` query to print all pods in `Running` state:

```
kubectl  get pod -n mynamespace -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.phase=="Running")].metadata.name}{"\n"}'
nginx mongo busybox
```

Although, you have not asked for `ready` state, but following query can be used to **list pods in ready state**.

```
kubectl  get pod -n mynamespace -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.status.containerStatuses[*].ready.true}{.metadata.name}{ "\n"}{end}'
foo-mh6j7
nginx
mongo
busybox
```

Similarly, this can be done via `grep`:

```
kubectl get pod -n $NAMESPACE |grep -P '\s+([1-9]+)\/\1\s+'
```

**NOTE:** Either of the solution will not prevent `pods` from getting respawned **if** they are created via `replicaset` or `deployment`  or `statefulset` etc. This means, they will get deleted and respawned.

Answer (score 5):

You could filter and delete running pods by:

```
kubectl delete pods -n <NAMESPACE> --field-selector=status.phase=Running
```

Answer (score 3):

To directly answer the question from the topic summary, for people who found this question, but want delete actually every pod, not only running ones.

Simply do:

```
kubectl delete pods -n <NAMESPACE> --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shellscript I made to achieve the task,

```sh
i=0 && for pod in $(kubectl get pods | grep 'Running')
  do 
    if [ `expr $i % 5` == 0 ]
      then kubectl delete pod $pod
    fi
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

I found that when we loop over `kubectl get pods | grep 'Running'`, every 5th word is a **pod name**.

So I basically wrote the script to take ***every 5th-word*** from the loop and execute whatever command I want on it.

Still, this feels like a **naive** approach. Feel free to share a **better one**.